# first tab elementor after the page loaded it overflow width

Tags: tabs, elementor

I encountered an issue with the Tab Elementor widget in my WordPress website. I'm using a template with this widget, but when the page loads, it overflows the width, causing the content to extend beyond the viewport. I tried rearranging the tabs, and the problem seems to be specific to the first tab. When I remove the template and simply write a regular paragraph, it works fine.

I'd like to continue using the template because it provides the desired layout and design. I'm using the Hello Child theme, which is supposed to maintain compatibility with Elementor.

I've tried troubleshooting this problem by inspecting the CSS, but I can't pinpoint the issue. It seems related to how the template interacts with the Tab Elementor widget. I'm looking for guidance on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the tab widget works as intended while still using the template. Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated.